# How to get back storage capacity from BOOTCAMP_VOL in Mojave without formatting?

Tags: hard-drive, bootcamp, imac

[image: screenshot]
I have a hybrid drive version of iMac, and from the start I have bootcamp installed in my iMac but barely ever used it. The OS has upgraded many times and not it is on Mojave. I realized a while ago that bootcamp is no longer available on hybrid driver, but I didn't bother because I don't use it anyways. I am just curious now if I can reclaim the storage capacity from the BOOTCAMP_VOL (250GB in my case) without formatting the entire drive (the time cost is just too high, I don't feel that 250GB of storage capacity would worth the trouble).

Answer (score 0):

Open Bootcamp utility and hit the uninstall button. It’s in Applications/Utilities.

Comment: There is no "Bootcamp utility" in Applications/Utilities. There is this "Boot Camp Assistant" that would guide me to install a new bootcamp (during which would fail, because my hard drive doesn't support bootcamp), without deleting the old one.